# cron not running a bash script that uses date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I'm testing a script that executes sub-scripts for the daily rotation of logging files:

`59 23 * * * /home/[username]/work/Rotate.sh`

this .sh file calls a number of other shell scripts, each of them working similarly to this:

```
folderName=$(date +%B)
folderPath="/data/logs/archive/"
currentDate=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
targetFile="/data/logs/logfile.log"

sudo mkdir $folderPath
sudo mkdir $folderPath$folderName

cp $targetFile $folderPath$folderName/logfile.$currentDate.log

echo "" > $targetFile
```

Directly calling Rotate.sh from terminal works as intended (using the command `sudo sh work/Rotate.sh`), but when I've reduced the crons timing to shorter intervals I haven't gotten any results at all. Is it possible that some aspect of my shell script is breaking the cron job? Have I missed something in the declaration of the line in crontab -e?

Comment: Where are `$ArchivePath` and `$ArchivePath$ArchiveName` declared. Does the `cron` user have execute permissions on each of the other scripts called?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake I made editing the code snippet for showing people let me adjust that.

Comment: If you're getting the results you want using sudo, shouldn't you should be using sudo in the cron job too?

Comment: I've used sudo crontab -e but that doesn't get me the results I need either. Do you mean write out the cron task as ```59 23 * * * sudo /home/[username]/work/Rotate.sh```?

Comment: Yes I do mean to use it in the job itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common reason for such failures is because your CRON Environment is the bare minimum environment supported by system. Its not aware of additional environment settings which is made available to you via shell.

A easy work around in such cases is to source .profile from your Shell Script. Putting below command at start of your file must help you to get this resolved.

```
source $HOME/.profile
```

Another way to do this would be to source the same in CRONJOB itself.

```
59 23 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /home/[username]/work/Rotate.sh
```

Comment: Thank you! I've got it sorted, feels like a huge relief.